# Route 53 + URL for AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am new to AWS and I am posed with a problem. Every time we build a new AWS Lambda it has a different URL to hit it. Is it possible to use CloudWatch to trigger a Lambda that then changes Route 53 records to point towards new Lambda builds?

Comment: You need the trinity: Api Gateway + Cloudfront + Route53

Comment: AWS Lambda functions don't have URLs. Maybe you are also using API Gateway? If that's the case, you want to use a [Custom Domain Name](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html) that is constant across deployments of new Lambda functions. You don't need to trigger another Lambda to change Route 53 in that case.